# Converting VBA HTML to C#

Tags: c#, html, vba

Can someone convert or tell me how to implement the below HTML so I can use it in a C method? Its for a STMP email which I have working, I just need the body in this format which I got from VBA.

```
    sBody = sBody & sRequestTypeDescription & " analysis requested"
    sBody = sBody & "<BR><BR>"

    If Len(sAssignComments) > 3 Then
       sBody = sBody & "<BR>"
       sBody = sBody & "Please note these additional comments from the assigner: "
       sBody = sBody & "<BR><BR>"
       sBody = sBody & "<b>" & sAssignComments & "</b>"
       sBody = sBody & "<BR><BR>"
    End If
    sBody = sBody & "<Table border=""1"">"
    sBody = sBody & "<TR>"
    sBody = sBody & "<TH align=""left""><NOBR><U>ProgramID</U></NOBR></TH>"
    sBody = sBody & "<TH align=""center""><NOBR><U>Cedant</U></NOBR></TH>"
    sBody = sBody & "<TH align=""center""><NOBR><U>UW</U></NOBR></TH>"
    sBody = sBody & "<TH align=""center""><NOBR><U>Due By</U></NOBR></TH>"
    sBody = sBody & "<TH align=""center""><NOBR><U>Notes</U></NOBR></TH>"
    sBody = sBody & "<TH align=""center""><NOBR><U>Assigned By</U></NOBR></TH>"
    sBody = sBody & "</TR>    "

    sBody = sBody & "<TR>"
    sBody = sBody & "<TD align=""left""><NOBR>" & g_ProgramID & "</NOBR></TD>"
    sBody = sBody & "<TD align=""right""><NOBR>" & oRS.Fields("Cedant") & "</NOBR></TD>"
    sBody = sBody & "<TD align=""right""><NOBR>" & sUWCode & "</NOBR></TD>"
    sBody = sBody & "<TD align=""Center""><NOBR>" & Format(dRequired, "mm/dd/yy") & "</NOBR></TD>"
    sBody = sBody & "<TD align=""left"" width=""200"">" & oRS("Comments") & "</TD>"
    sBody = sBody & "<TD align=""right""><NOBR>" & sAssignedBy & "</NOBR></TD>"
    sBody = sBody & "</TR>"

    sBody = sBody & "</TABLE>"
    sBody = sBody & "<BR><BR>"
```

Below answers were really helpful

Comment: HTML is the same in C#, do you need to know how to append strings in C# ?

Comment: change all `sBody = sBody &` to `sBody += ` and then all & to +
All ifs will be on the form `if (statement){` and all end-ifs will be } - for example `if (sAssignComments.length > 3) {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SO is not a translation service but I like these tasks

You need to fix oRS.Fields("Cedant")and Format(dRequired, "mm/dd/yy") yourself

- change all sBody = sBody & to sBody +=
- all & to +
- All ifs will be on the form `if (statement) {` and all end-ifs will be `}`
- Add semicolons to each statement
- investigate the [stringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)

Minimum effort:

```
sBody += sRequestTypeDescription + " analysis requested";
sBody += "<BR><BR>";

if (sAssignComments.length > 3) {
   sBody += "<BR>";
   sBody += "Please note these additional comments from the assigner: ";
   sBody += "<BR><BR>";
   sBody += "<b>" + sAssignComments + "</b>";
   sBody += "<BR><BR>";
}
sBody += "<Table border=\"1\">";
sBody += "<TR>";
sBody += "<TH align=\"left\"><NOBR><U>ProgramID</U></NOBR></TH>";
sBody += "<TH align=\"center\"><NOBR><U>Cedant</U></NOBR></TH>";
sBody += "<TH align=\"center\"><NOBR><U>UW</U></NOBR></TH>";
sBody += "<TH align=\"center\"><NOBR><U>Due By</U></NOBR></TH>";
sBody += "<TH align=\"center\"><NOBR><U>Notes</U></NOBR></TH>";
sBody += "<TH align=\"center\"><NOBR><U>Assigned By</U></NOBR></TH>";
sBody += "</TR>    ";

sBody += "<TR>";
sBody += "<TD align=\"left\"><NOBR>" + g_ProgramID + "</NOBR></TD>";
sBody += "<TD align=\"right\"><NOBR>" + oRS.Fields("Cedant") + "</NOBR></TD>";
sBody += "<TD align=\"right\"><NOBR>" + sUWCode + "</NOBR></TD>";
sBody += "<TD align=\"center\"><NOBR>" + Format(dRequired, "mm/dd/yy") + "</NOBR></TD>";
sBody += "<TD align=\"left"" width=\"200\">" + oRS("Comments") + "</TD>";
sBody += "<TD align=\"right\"><NOBR>" + sAssignedBy + "</NOBR></TD>";
sBody += "</TR>";

sBody += "</TABLE>";
sBody += "<BR><BR>";
```

Using StringBuilder instead (without going into TOO many loops like appendFormat)

- All `sBody +=` to `sb.AppendLine(`
- all `";` to `");`
- change Print sBody if that is what you have at the end of the sub, to `return sb.ToString();`

Result:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine(sRequestTypeDescription + " analysis requested");
sb.AppendLine("<BR><BR>");
if (sAssignComments.length > 3) {
   sb.AppendLine("<BR>");
   sb.AppendLine("Please note these additional comments from the assigner: ");
   sb.AppendLine("<BR><BR>");
   sb.AppendLine("<b>" + sAssignComments + "</b>");
   sb.AppendLine("<BR><BR>");
}
sb.AppendLine("<Table border=\"1\">");
sb.AppendLine("<TR>");
sb.AppendLine("<TH align=\"left\"><NOBR><U>ProgramID</U></NOBR></TH>");
sb.AppendLine("<TH align=\"center\"><NOBR><U>Cedant</U></NOBR></TH>");
sb.AppendLine("<TH align=\"center\"><NOBR><U>UW</U></NOBR></TH>");
sb.AppendLine("<TH align=\"center\"><NOBR><U>Due By</U></NOBR></TH>");
sb.AppendLine("<TH align=\"center\"><NOBR><U>Notes</U></NOBR></TH>");
sb.AppendLine("<TH align=\"center\"><NOBR><U>Assigned By</U></NOBR></TH>");
sb.AppendLine("</TR>    ");

sb.AppendLine("<TR>");
sb.AppendLine("<TD align=\"left\"><NOBR>" + g_ProgramID + "</NOBR></TD>");
sb.AppendLine("<TD align=\"right\"><NOBR>" + oRS.Fields("Cedant") + "</NOBR></TD>");
sb.AppendLine("<TD align=\"right\"><NOBR>" + sUWCode + "</NOBR></TD>");
sb.AppendLine("<TD align=\"center\"><NOBR>" + Format(dRequired, "mm/dd/yy") + "</NOBR></TD>");
sb.AppendLine("<TD align=\"left"" width=\"200\">" + oRS("Comments") + "</TD>");
sb.AppendLine("<TD align=\"right\"><NOBR>" + sAssignedBy + "</NOBR></TD>");
sb.AppendLine("</TR>");

sb.AppendLine("</TABLE>");
sb.AppendLine("<BR><BR>");
```

Comment: StringBuilder might be better suited to this?

Comment: Of course but I just did 3 change all in my editor

Comment: Fair point. Just thought, you're going to the effort to alter the code for them, where most people wouldn't, so why not throw something in for them to learn about.

Comment: Ok, Never used C# but added a StrigBuilder anyway

Comment: Good effort. StringBuilder has much better performance than string Mystring +=.

Comment: I have great TextPad-FU :)

Comment: Thanks! I am new to this and learning a lot

Comment: See update for the change statements

Comment: @bossman1111 - note that when you want to form this into a string from StringBuilder you will need to do sb.ToString() in this case.